# What is wrong with this prepared SQL statement?

Tags: php

This does not seem to work, no errors, just doesn't return anything:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM deadfrontier.items WHERE item LIKE "?"');
    $stmt->execute([$test]);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['item'];
    }
```

But, this does:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM deadfrontier.items WHERE item LIKE "RG6"');
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['item'];
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

(Edit: Here's the `$test` variable: `$test = "RG6";`

Comment: You don't use the quotes in the query string when using placeholders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a PHP expert by any means ([@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) is though), but I don't think you need to quote escape your strings inside the prepared statement.  Handling the escaping of strings is one of the very reasons why you would want to use a prepared statement.  Instead, just use a `?` by itself to handle the string parameter and let PDO do the work for you:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM deadfrontier.items WHERE item LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute([$test]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['item'];
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I remember thinking I should try that but it slipped from my head lol.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are forgot to bind the parameter in prepared statement

Below is the example

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM deadfrontier.items WHERE item LIKE "?"');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);     // binding the value

$stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['item'];
    }
```

Please try this will work in your case

Comment: You can pass an array of parameters into the execute method to bind them, so his code is valid